# Create a listing inside of a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift3

I am writing a Swift app, and on my main screen I have a long scrollview with several regions of content in it (upcoming events, announcements, and then featured products, and finally some basic info). So it's this really long scroll, and you can swipe down to the bottom.

So visualize 4 boxes, if you will, stacked vertically.

The 3rd box shows featured products. This can be anywhere from 1 to 30 items, depending upon any filters the user has in their settings.

My first try was using a UITableView for region#3 inside of this parent scrollview, but the problem is it only shows the first few items/rows and then the rest you scroll inside the table (which is the default/natural behavior of a table, right?). Unfortunately, the requirement I have is that the inner table can't scroll - it needs to display everything at once and you have to scroll (in the main UIScrollView) to get to the bottom (not scroll inside the inner uitableview scroll). Also, everyone seems to say don't use UITableView inside of a scroll.

So how do I create some sort of list where I create one template (like how you would in a xib/tablecell, and then assign a data source to it, and then repeat down without scrolling? Should I use a tableview after all, and just make the height of it very high and turn scrolling off?

Do I somehow instantiate xibs in a for loop and assign them dynamically to some view?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Table View with Grouped style. That would make it fairly easy to keep your "4 boxes" segregated, and your "3rd box" would simply be 1 to 30 rows in that section.

On note: you *don't* want to have a "very tall" table view - or any other type of view, for that matter. You want to allow iOS to manage memory for you, and to load and display only those parts of your content that is visible at any one time.

In other words, use a table view like its designed to be used :)